# How to parse multi-line CSV into multidimensional associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

Content of `$csv_content` is:

```
1415797658,456ABC,789,123,"bla"
1415797656,654XYZ,897,567,"foo"
1415797654,639HJW,465,146,"bar"
```

`str_getcsv(file_get_contents($csv_content))` results in:

```
array
  0 => string '1415797658' (length=10)
  1 => string '456ABC' (length=6)
  2 => string '789' (length=3)
  3 => string '123' (length=3)
  4 => string 'bla' (length=3)
  5 => string '1415797656' (length=10)
  6 => string '654XYZ' (length=6)
  7 => string '897' (length=3)
  8 => string '567' (length=3)
  9 => string 'foo' (length=3)
  10 => string '1415797654' (length=10)
  11 => string '639HJW' (length=6)
  12 => string '465' (length=3)
  13 => string '146' (length=3)
  14 => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Desired result:

```
array
  0 =>
    array
      'timestamp' => string '1415797658' (length=10)
      'id' => string '456ABC' (length=6)
      'id2' => string '789' (length=3)
      'id3' => string '123' (length=3)
      'text' => string 'bla' (length=3)
  1 =>
    array
      'timestamp' => string '1415797656' (length=10)
      'id' => string '654XYZ' (length=6)
      'id2' => string '897' (length=3)
      'id3' => string '567' (length=3)
      'text' => string 'foo' (length=3)
  2 =>
    array
      'timestamp' => string '1415797654' (length=10)
      'id' => string '639HJW' (length=6)
      'id2' => string '465' (length=3)
      'id2' => string '146' (length=3)
      'text' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

What would be the neatest way to do this?

Comment: The examples shown in the docs for PHP's built-in [fgetcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) function might give you a few ideas

Comment: Your csv should have header. You could expect header, then parse it in first and use first row as keys for the assoc array. After that you parse each row and push new array into another array containing the row with key => value association.

Comment: @LauriOrgla: CSV is given as it is.

Comment: If the CSV doesn't have headers, then you'll need to assign the array keys yourself, but the principle of looping the file using fgetcsv() still applies

Comment: If you want to be really clever, you use an [SplFileObject](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$array=array();
$handle=fopen($csv_content,'r');
while ($row=fgetcsv($handle)){
   $array[]=array(
              'timestamp' => $row[0],
              'id' => $row[1],
              'id2' => $row[2],
              'id3' => $row[3],
              'text' => $row[4]
           );
}
```